# Display data dynamically on ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET application with some web API endpoint.

I want to append the data displayed on the home page every time it is received by the endpoint.

How can I achieve it in the simplest way. I would appreciate any help.

EDIT:

Api Controller:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    public static event EventHandler<string> DataPosted;

    public IHttpActionResult Get(string value)
    {
        DataPosted?.Invoke(this, value);
        return Ok();
    }
}
```

Home page Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ValuesController.DataPosted += (s_, e_) =>
        {
            ViewBag.MyData += Environment.NewLine + e_;
        };

        return View();
    }
}
```

Home page View:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Output</h2>
        <p>@ViewBag.MyData</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This, of course, doesn't work. I think I need to find a way to force part of the page responsible for displaying `@ViewBag.MyData` to refresh. I also tried with partial view but without any luck.

Comment: Do you have Grid ?
when you say append you mean refresh the page or without refreshing the page the data will be shown ? 
What do you mean dynamically , is the data structure  diff every time ?

Comment: Sounds like you want Ajax.

Comment: May you provide a code example of your endpoint please.

Comment: @GIVE-ME-CHICKEN In the ApiController I have a static event which is triggered every time a call to the endpoint is made. The event args contain the data from the call. In the homepage controller I added the event handler which I wanted to force the data to be displayed. This may be not the way to go, but it was the first thing that came to my mind and since I'm a ASP noob I couldn't think of anything else. I tried to pass the data by ViewBag so far.

Comment: @Szybki thats better, but I meant edit your question to include actual code.

Comment: @Szybki If you are using an endpoint, it should return Json or Xml, then a client would handle the data however it sees fit.  If you are treating it more like a MVC Controller then it might return some view data, which the client would still handle on the page unless you perform a post back.

Comment: @GIVE-ME-CHICKEN I edited the question and added my code.

Comment: @Szybki I just want to make sure I have correct understanding of what you want to do here. Are you trying to do the following? -  If ValuesController.Get(string value) is called, you want to update the TItle of the homepage?

Comment: @GIVE-ME-CHICKEN not title but the part that is displaying the contents of MyData variable from ViewBag (I removed the misleading part of the code). But yeah, It should update as soon as `ValuesController.Get(string value)` is called. Or, if it's not possible or not effective, it should update on timer, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the approach to this problem is incorrect.

You have a browser that is making a request to your web app to view the homepage.
The web app will serve the homepage to the browser with the contents of ViewBag.MyData.

You have an endpoint ValuesController.Get(string value) and when its called you want it to update the value in ViewBag.MyData and inevitably update the homepage with its contents.

The problems are:

1. When you call ValuesController.Get(string value), it won't return anything to the browser because it does not know how to.
2. You are using ViewBag which isn't an appropriate storage type for what you are trying to do. Mainly because it only holds data for the lifetime of the current request. When another request comes in, its gone.

Fixes are:

1. Change ValuesController.Get so that all it does is store the value somewhere (I would go for a database, but if you need something quick and dirty, try creating a static class with 1 static string property and store it there, or perhaps storing it in an application variable).
2. Create a new endpoint called something like GetValue(), and all that should do is retrieve that value from wherever you stored it.
3. Write client-side code (I would use JQuery/Ajax) to periodically call GetValue() endpoint which simply returns the most up-to-date value you wish to update on your homepage.

If the requirement is to persist the value passed into ValuesController.Get(string value) further than the lifetime of the application, then I would highly recommend storing that value in a database somewhere. Values stored in static variables and application variables only live as long as the AppDomain does (if you restart your web app, or close it, those values or lost, but in a database, its still there).

Comment: @Szybki did that make sense, if not let me know if I can help further

Comment: Yes, it does make sense to me. Thanks for pointing out that I should poll for data from client side rather than building event driven solution and that I shouldn't use ViewBag for this purpose. That's exactly what I needed to know. I'd also like to thank you for pulling me on the tongue for info you needed in order to help me and for the effort you've put in the answer as others would only downvote the question and mark it to close.